# If String is in Variables in List

Tags: python, string, list, variables

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to make Python find a string (through user input) that is in several variables which are contained in a list.

Hopefully this example can explain what I am trying to do:

```
list = [var1, var2, var3]

var1 = input("x")
var2 = input("x")
var3 = input("x")

if ("x") = in (list):
   print("x was found in all 3 variables in list!")
```

Comment: You should experiment with writing a loop that runs N times and puts the results in an array, then loop over that array to count how many match.

Comment: what happens when you run this code?  do you get the output you expect?

Comment: `is in (list)`: don't try to speak english to python.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Thank you for taking the time to present an example to explain your question. In future, try to only post code that you have actually run, along with any error message or output that confuses you. It is obvious that your code snippet is psuedo-code, not actual python code. I'm looking forward to seeing more questions (and answers!) from you.

Comment: @ tadman Not sure what that means. I'm not so experienced with Python yet.
@ MohammadAthar Nope, not even clsoe.
@ Jean-FrançoisFabre Haha, you got me there... I tend to do that (luckily it was written like = in the actual code)
@Robᵩ Hi Rob, thank you very much for the warm welcome. There was quite a bit of code involved around it and I wasn't sure what to copy copy from that, so I decided to summarize it a bit, by writing a pseudo code. But I'll try harder net time. And thanks, I'm looking forward to a day where I can pass my experience on to other newcomers!

Comment: @mwaning - You are welcome. In the meanwhile, try to take the [tour] and especially read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations), along with the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function. By passing a [generator expresion](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to `all()`, you can examine all of the list items.

Also note that you referenced your `var...` variables before they were set, and there is no `is in` operator.

Try this:

```
var1 = input("x")
var2 = input("x")
var3 = input("x")

lst = [var1, var2, var3]

if all("x" in item for item in lst):
   print("x was found in all 3 variables.")
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But I'm afraid it doesn't work. In my code the vars were already set before the input, because it gave an error about that before.
After applying your fix it still got completely ignored. Not sure what's going wrong now...